# Using jQuery .remove() only removes first list item

Tags: jquery, html

I have a simple form, that allows someone to add/remove extra telephone numbers. For some reason, I cannot see the error in my Javascript. The user can add new numbers as list items without any issues--each list item has a button to remove the list item. If the user clicks on the first list items remove button, the item is removed. None of the list items that were added with JS will be removed from the page.

This seems so simple, but I'm stumped. I've spent the last two hours trying to solve this with many searches in stackoverflow and on google. I know I will feel silly when it's resolved, but I could use some help with this.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="telRow">
  <li id="telid_1234">
    ONE <button class="telRowRemove">-</button>
  </li>
</ul>

<div>
  <button class="telRowAdd">+</button>
</div>

<div id="errors">No errors</div>

<div class="emptyTel" style="display: none;">
<input type="text" name="tel_no[]" />
<button class="telRowRemove">-</button> 
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.telRowAdd').on('click', function() {
     var Container = $('ul.telRow');
     var newrow = '<li>ONE <button class="telRowRemove">-</button></li>';
     Container.append(newrow);
      $('#errors').text('Added');
  });

  $('.telRowRemove').click(function() {
      $(this).parent('li').remove();
      $('#errors').text('Removed');
  });
});
```

The remove button has a class of .telRowRemove, so in theory clicking on the button would trigger $('.telRowRemove').click, but it only does this for the original list item on the page, none of the rest of the list items.

I have a sample setup on JS Bin here http://jsbin.com/omanij/1/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your selector only binds the event to the elements that exist when you look for them. Use event delegation to match the ones that appear later on:

```
$('#parent_of_tel_rows').on('click', '.telRowRemove', function() {
    $(this).parent('li').remove();
    $('#errors').text('Removed');
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you Blender, that works. Using the terminology 'event delegation' I also now understand why.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your following buttons won't work is because they are dynamically added to the DOM, and the click event that you bind to won't fire for future elements.

Use the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead, it will ensure future elements are bonded too.

See the updated example here: http://jsbin.com/omanij/5/edit

Comment: Thanks Kagawa. I had tried .on() previously without success. Blenders explanation was slightly more accurate for my issue.

Comment: See my example, it's working. Anyway, glad you found the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

you can find working model below in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/btjcz/

```
$('.telRowAdd').on('click', function () {
        var Container = $('ul.telRow');
        var newrow = $('<li>ONE </li>');
        var btnRemove = $('<button class="telRowRemove">-</button>');

        btnRemove.click(function () {
            $(this).parent('li').remove();
            $('#errors').text('Removed');
        });
        newrow.append(btnRemove);



        Container.append(newrow);
        $('#errors').text('Added');
    });
```